# Given a matrix of the form $A=a\otimes b$ then $|A|_{nm}=|a|_{n} |b|_{m}$

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, tensor-products

I consider this matrix in $\mathbb{M}^{m\times n}$
$$A=a\otimes b,$$ with $b\in \mathbb{R}^m$ and $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

I would like to prove that $|A|_{nm}=|a|_{n} |b|_{m}$,
where $|.|_{p}$ is the module on $\mathbb{R}^p$.

Is there a simple way to prove this?

Should I use some other matrix norms to prove that?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a comment, the notation $|x|_p$ is really awckward. This is usually denoted $|x|_2$, irrespective of the size of the matrix. As this is standard, I'll use this notation.

Assuming that by $|x|_2$ you mean $(\sum_{k,j}|x_{kj}|^2)^{1/2}$, this follows from the equalities
$$
|x|_2^2=\text{Tr}\,(x^Tx),\ \ \ \ \text{ and } \ \ \ \ \text{Tr}\,(a\otimes b)=\text{Tr}(a)\,\text{Tr}(b).
$$
Indeed,
$$
|A|_{2}^2=\text{Tr}((a\otimes b)^T(a\otimes b))=\text{Tr}(a^Ta\otimes b^Tb)=\text{Tr}(a^Ta)\,\text{Tr}(b^Tb)=|a|_2^2\,|b|_2^2
$$

---